# Find the longest word in a string

Tags: strings

Is there a simple way to get the longest word in a string? I would know how to program it in some other languages, but I'm afraid my latex kung-fu is not up to par...

To make it clear, I want to make a function \longword{} that (for example) on input {I am an annoying stackexchange user} will return "stackexchange".

Comment: Can you give an example and some motivation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about simple, but I made this for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\longest[1]{
  \setsepchar{ }
  \xdef\sentence{#1}
  \readlist\wordlist\sentence
  \def\longestword{}
  \def\longestwordcount{0}
  \newcounter{@wordlength}
  \foreachitem\word\in\wordlist{
    \@getstringlength{\word}{@wordlength}
    \ifnum\the@wordlength>\longestwordcount\relax%
      \xdef\longestword{\word}
      \xdef\longestwordcount{\the@wordlength}
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% Count number of strings
\longest{the lazy dog stackexchange}
\obeyspaces The longest word was \longestword and had \longestwordcount characters
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! To make it work properly I had to change \def\longestword{\word} to \xdef\longestword{\word}. Otherwise it always gives the last word as \longestword (which in your example makes no difference, probably why you didn't catch the bug)

Comment: @Alexbib true! Because the `\word` macro keeps changing and the `\xdef` expands it fully. Fixed in the answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \longestword } { m }
  { \alexbib_longest_word:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npx \alexbib_longest_word:n #1
 {
   \exp_not:N \__alexbib_longest_word:nnw
     { 0 } { } #1 ~
     \exp_not:N \q_recursion_tail \c_space_tl \exp_not:N\q_recursion_stop
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__alexbib_longest_word:nnw #1#2#3 ~
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn {#3} {#2}
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \tl_count:n {#3} } > { #1 }
      {
        \exp_args:Nf \__alexbib_longest_word:nnw
          { \int_eval:n { \tl_count:n {#3} } } {#3}
      }
      { \__alexbib_longest_word:nnw {#1} {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\longestword{I am an annoying stackexchange user}
\end{document}
```

(I've assumed that we are counting 'length' on a token basis: I'm not sure if for example `\'{e}` counts as one or two letters.)